# Sending PHP Information with Mail and Receipt

Tags: php, jquery, email

My dilemma is sending my form data using php.
Of course I have looked at multiple articles to solve the issue myself.
After trying to adapt my code to fit the requirements, I have been unsuccessful because the php submission does not complete (I am assume.)
Specifically, after hitting submit, there is no content displayed on the next page nor does an email window pop up.
(I'd prefer that all the data displays in a pop mailing window.
I would not be hurt if it is not in the realm of possibility if only html, css, jquery, and php languages.)

If you need to see the html, I would be happy to post it as well.

PHP - Code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "random@example.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$client = $_POST['client'];
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$checkin = $_POST['datepicker'];
$due = $_POST['duedate'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
$phone = $_POST['phoneno'];

$confirm = $_POST['confirm'];

$file1 = $_POST['file1'];
$file2 = $_POST['file2'];

$prime = $_POST['prime'];
$sec = $_POST['second'];
$tri = $_POST['third'];

$dim = $_POST['dimtype'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$length = $_POST['length'];

$details = $_POST['details'];

$design = $_POST['design'];

$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['details'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['details'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $client . ", we will contact you shortly.";

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
{

$injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
    ?>
```

HTML -- This is the HTML with is basically a form that users may use to fill out basic information. After resolving this issue, I will implement Javascript/jQuery script to validate form before submitting it to PHP. 
Again, I am only looking for a resolution for PHP, not javascripting.

```
<form id="project_form" action="_php/mobile.php" method="post" autocomplete="on">
```

```
<label for="client">Project Name:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="Ace Designs" name="client" id="client">
<br />

<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="Earl" name="lname" id="lname">
<br />

<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="Torey" name="fname" id="fname">
<br />

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="YourAceDesigner@gmail.com" id="email">
<br />


<label for="date">Date:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="03/07/2017" name="date" id="date">
<br />

<label for="checkin">Check-In Date:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate: -20,
      maxDate: "+1M +10D"
    });
  });

</script>
<br />

<label for="checkin">Check-In Date:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="03/14/2017" name="checkin" id="checkin">
<br />

<label for="state">State:</label>
<br />
<select name="state" id="state" style="margin:.1em 0em 1em .8em; width: 13.3em;">
  <option value="blank">Select State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br />

<label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="99999 or 99999-99" name="duedate" id="zip">
<br />

<label for="phone">Phone No:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="val" placeholder="800-999-9999" name="phone" id="phone">
<br />
```

```
<div id="field" style="text-align: center;">
<h3 style="
background-color:#5f2b87; 
color:#fff;
padding: .7em 0em .7em; 0em;
margin-top:1em;
margin-bottom:.3em;">
Contact Information</h3>

<div name="optionz">
  Design:
  <select id="design" name='design' style="margin-top:1em;">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Design</option>
    <option value="166.25">Logo</option>
    <option value="256.25">Brochure(6pages)</option>
    <option value="35.25">Print Illustration</option>
    <option value="120.25">Vector Illustration</option>
    <option value="41.25">Flyer/Handbill</option>
    <option value="41.00">Flyer(template)</option>
    <option value="66.75">Banner</option>
    <option value="250">Billboard</option>
    <option value="131.25">Business Card</option>
    <option value="412.75">Website(static)</option>
    <option value="1212.75">Website(dynamic)</option>
    <option value="262.75">Website(Template)</option>
    <option value="60.25">Photography (1HR)</option>
    <option value="106.25">Photography (3HR)</option>
    <option value="231.25">Photography (6HR)</option>
    <option value="326.25">Photography (8HR)</option>
  </select>
  <br /> Confirm:
  <select id="confirm" name='confirm' style="margin-top:1em;">
    <option disabled selected>Confirm Design</option>
    <option>Logo</option>
    <option>Brochure(6pages)</option>
    <option>Print Illustration</option>
    <option>Vector Illustration</option>
    <option>Flyer/Handbill</option>
    <option>Flyer(template)</option>
    <option>Banner</option>
    <option>Billboard</option>
    <option>Business Card</option>
    <option>Website(static)</option>
    <option>Website(dynamic)</option>
    <option>Website(Template)</option>
    <option>Photography (1HR)</option>
    <option>Photography (3HR)</option>
    <option>Photography (6HR)</option>
    <option>Photography (8HR)</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="my_hidden_field" />
</div>
<br />

<div name="files" id="files">
  File Types
  <br />
  <select name="file1">
    <option disabled selected>Choose File</option>
    <option>.eps</option>
    <option>.jpeg</option>
    <option>.jpeg2000</option>
    <option>.tiff</option>
    <option>.gif</option>
    <option>.bmp</option>
    <option>.png</option>
    <option>.pdf</option>
    <option>.pbm</option>
    <option>.psd</option>
    <option>.ai</option>
    <option>.indd</option>
    <option>.dwt</option>
    <option>other</option>
  </select>
  <select name="file2">
    <option disabled selected>Choose File</option>
    <option>.jpeg</option>
    <option>.jpeg2000</option>
    <option>.tiff</option>
    <option>.gif</option>
    <option>.bmp</option>
    <option>.png</option>
    <option>.eps</option>
    <option>.pdf</option>
    <option>.pbm</option>
    <option>.psd</option>
    <option>.ai</option>
    <option>.indd</option>
    <option>.dwt</option>
    <option>other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br />

<div name="colors" id="colorz">
  Color Scheme
  <br />
  <input name="prime" size="8" class="jscolor {hash:true}">
  <input name="second" size="8" class="jscolor {hash:true}">
  <input name="third" size="8" class="jscolor {hash:true}">
</div>
<br />

<div name="dimensions" id="dimenz">
  Dimensions
  <br />
  <select name="dimtype">
    <option disabled selected>Unit of Measure</option>
    <option>Pixels</option>
    <option>Points</option>
    <option>Picas</option>
    <option>Inches</option>
    <option>Millimeters</option>
    <option>Centimeters</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input size="6" name="width" placeholder="WIDTH" type="number">
  <br />
  <input size="6" name="length" placeholder="LENGTH" type="number">

</div>

<br />
<div>
  Project Notes:
  <br />
  <textarea name="details" rows="6" cols="40" style="margin-top: 1em;"></textarea>
</div>

<div style="color:#fff;">
  Total:
  <div name="sum" id='sum'>$0.00</div>
</div>


<div id="float">
  <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
</form> 
enter code here
```

Comment: Hmm. It would be helpful if you could post the HTML for the form as well. It's quite possible that you have mismatched variable names or an invalid submission.

Comment: I added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete answer I managed to find, But this has the best result of what I want to happen.

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        Project Name: <?php echo $_POST["client"]; ?><br />
        Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br />
        Date: <?php echo $_POST["date"]; ?><br />
        Check-In: <?php echo $_POST["datepicker"]; ?><br />
        Due Date: <?php echo $_POST["duedate"]; ?><br />
        State: <?php echo $_POST["state"]; ?><br />
        Zip: <?php echo $_POST["zipcode"]; ?><br />
        Phone No: <?php echo $_POST["phoneno"]; ?><br />

    Design: <?php echo $_POST["confirm"]; ?><br />

    File1: <?php echo $_POST["file1"]; ?><br />
    File2: <?php echo $_POST["file2"]; ?><br />
    Color1: <?php echo $_POST["prime"]; ?><br />
    Color2: <?php echo $_POST["second"]; ?><br />
    Color3: <?php echo $_POST["third"]; ?><br />
    Dimension Type: <?php echo $_POST["dimtype"]; ?><br />
    Width: <?php echo $_POST["width"]; ?><br />
    Length: <?php echo $_POST["length"]; ?><br />
    Details: <?php echo $_POST["details"]; ?>

    <br /><br />

    Price: <?php echo $_POST["design"]; ?>
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
   } 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the following discrepancy in your code

```
$to = "random@example.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
```

That Recipient address has a hard-coded email address and Sender address is coming from `$_POST['email']`. Kindly ensure this is correct...

Kindly refer the following PHP Mail Script, it has the functionality of CC too. No need of two Mail function.

```
<?php
    /* Simple Plain eMail */
    $from = "support@bbminfo.com";
    $to = "abc@gmail.com";
    $email_cc = "info@bbminfo.com";
    $email_bcc = "xyz@yahoo.com";
    $subject = "Invitation for New YGen SEO Tool";
    $message = "Dear User, We are very glad to inform and invite you, that BBM's YGen SEO Tool (bbminfo.com) is now ready to launch on 15th August, 2013.";

    /* Header Information */
    $header = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Cc: " . strip_tags($email_cc) . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Bcc: " . strip_tags($email_bcc) . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\r\n";

    $flg = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    if($flg == true) {
        echo("Your message has been sent.");
    } else {
        echo("Failed to sent.");
    }
?>
```

I think it will help you...

Kindly refer the following link for more information about [PHP Mail function](http://www.bbminfo.com/Tutor/php_mail.php)

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, please [**summarise your link's points**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) in your answer itself. The link to the page could break in the future, which might [**detract from your answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). In fact, answers that are little more than a link [**may be deleted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). A few sentences or some sample code covering the key points from your link would make it so that your answer remains sound, even if the link no longer works :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification input and I appreciate your link @B.Balamanigandan. However the link that you provided is geared towards attaching elements as oppose to form submission and there are some broken links on the page itself. I'm sure the concept is similar. But I keep running into the issue that the page still does not load on both local and online servers.  I found another solution that echos the variables I need but I am still coming up short.

Answer (score -2):

In php some times mail function doesn't work as expected best practice is to use php mailer class which is easy to implement and gives you a lot of space to play.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)